# Relationship between sizes of a table and figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot figure out how to "synchronize" sizes of a table and a figure, so that the table lies completely within the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from string import ascii_uppercase
from random import choice

#content for the table
height = 9
width = 9
grid = [[choice(ascii_uppercase) for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

#desired size of a cell
cell_size = 0.3

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width * cell_size, height * cell_size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

the_table = ax.table(cellText=grid, loc='center')

for pos, cell in the_table._cells.items():
    cell._height = cell._width = cell_size

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

My understanding is that the area within the axis (+ some outer margins) **is** the figure - when I save it as an image file, it saves only this area, cropping all the rest, and the size of the image is 194x194, which matches the figure size and DPI:

```
fig.get_size_inches()
>>array([2.7, 2.7])
fig.dpi
>>72.0
```

So I guess my question is when I set cell size in the table, isn't it in inches (same as for figure size)? Or DPI for the table is different? I couldn't find any dpi-related methods or attributes for matplotlib.table.Table class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the cells is by default automatically adjusted to fit the width of the axes, if `loc="center"`.
What remains is to set the height of the cells. This is given in units of axes coordinates. So in order to fill the complete height of the axes (== 1 in axes coordinates), you can divide 1 by the number of rows in the table to get the height of each cell. Then set the height to all cells.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from string import ascii_uppercase
from random import choice

#content for the table
height = 9
width = 9
grid = [[choice(ascii_uppercase) for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]


fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
#ax.plot([0,2])

the_table = ax.table(cellText=grid, loc='center')
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)

cell_height = 1 / len(grid)
for pos, cell in the_table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_height(cell_height)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That key piece of info (cell height unit  =  fraction of axes) is what I was missing (and couldn't find anywhere in matplotlib docs)

Comment: The `table` docs are not complete at all. Improvements are welcome.